# How to use CursorLoader with multi Uri?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to get data of all music file from internal and external on device. I have used CursorLoader with LoaderManager. How can I merge two CursorLoader to one on onCreateLoader(int id,Bundle args):

```
CursorLoader firstLoader = new CursorLoader(this,MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projE, selection, argsArray, null);
CursorLoader secondLoader = new CursorLoader(this,MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projI, selection, argsArray, null);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `android.database.MergeCursor`

Comment: I'm sorry @pskink, I have updated my question.

Comment: so what do you have problems with `MergeCursor`? store the first `Cursor` somewhere and use `MergeCursor` when the second callback is fired

Comment: @pskink, if I use MergeCursor, I met error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: `selection` parameter has to have `BaseColumns._ID` column, verify it with  `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`

Comment: oops, of course not `selection` but `projection`